# AzureDevOps powershell task printing secrets parameters in logs as plain text when secret is escaped

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Im using **Powershell task** in my AzureDevops Release pipeline, i've configured **secrets** pipeline variables that are beeing passed to script by parameters in Arguments section this way:

```
-secret1 '$(secret1)' -secret2 '$(secret2)'
```

**secret1** contains special characters (e.g. "!", "$", "|") and inside build logs my secret1 is printed as plain text

For secret1 = **te$s!t** in logs its appear like **te_#removed#*s*#removed#_t**, secret2 is printed as expected

**Logs:**

```
##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.231.4
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
-secret1
te_#removed#_s_#removed#_t
-secret2
***
Formatted command: . 'AzureAgentPath\script.ps1' -secret1 *** -secret2 ***
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
```

Is there a way to hide this output? I've tried to wrap it or change task options but unsuccesfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the task code and found it is created by [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/Common/Sanitizer/ArgumentsSanitizer.ps1#L90). It is related to [enable shell tasks arguments parameter validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/inputs?view=azure-devops#shellTasksValidation).

> Detected characters in arguments that may not be executed correctly by the shell. Please escape special characters using backtick (`).

So I changed the variable value as the following and then it works. But the secret value will contain the backtick (`) in the end.

[image]

[image]

You can also report a problem [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) to request Azure DevOps fix the issue.